# Jira gadget is not working

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to develop a gadget that will ultimately incorporate ChartJS, but I am having issues with the default gadget, as it does not load.

The code I am putting into the attlassian-plugin.xml is the following:

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    </plugin-info>

    <!-- add our i18n resource -->
    <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="report"/>

    <!-- add our web resources -->
    <web-resource key="report-resources" name="report Web Resources">
        <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>

        <resource type="download" name="report.css" location="/css/report.css"/>
        <resource type="download" name="report.js" location="/js/report.js"/>
        <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>

        <context>report</context>
    </web-resource>

    <!-- publish our component -->
    <component key="myPluginComponent" class="com.wfs.report.MyPluginComponentImpl" public="true">
        <interface>com.wfs.report.MyPluginComponent</interface>
    </component>

    <!-- import from the product container -->
    <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties" />

<webwork1 key="demoaction" name="JTricks Demo Action" class="java.lang.Object">
  <actions>
    <action name="com.wfs.report.DemoAction" alias="DemoAction">
      <view name="input">/templates/input.vm</view>
      <view name="success">/templates/joy.vm</view>
      <view name="error">/templates/tears.vm</view>
    </action>
  </actions>
</webwork1>

<atlassian-plugin name="Hello World" key="example.plugin.helloworld" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>A basic gadget module</description>
    <vendor name="Atlassian Software Systems" url="http://www.atlassian.com"/>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </plugin-info>

  <gadget key="unique-gadget-key" location="gadget.xml"/>

</atlassian-plugin>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

and my gadget.xml which i put in the resources directory is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="JIRA Issues" author_email="adent@example.com" directory_title="JIRA Issues"
      screenshot="images/screenshot.png"
      thumbnail="images/thumbnail.png">
    <Optional feature="dynamic-height" />
  </ModulePrefs>

  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
       Hello, world!
     ]]>
   </Content> 
</Module>
</xml>
```

which I copied from https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Creating+your+Gadget+XML+Specification

yet I still get

[image]

Comment: Does the JIRA log show anything at the time you uploaded the module? Usually, if a plugin gets disabled on upload, JIRA will place some sort of complaint in the log file *at the time of upload* in either JIRA_HOME/logs/catalina.out and/or JIRA_DATA/log/atlassian-jira.log. Also, I see that you have a leading slash in the `location="/gadget.xml"` part of the `gadget` element in your atlassian-plugins.xml. You might try removing the slash to see what happens. (We never use leading slashes in our plugin descriptions, but I can't remember if it can be optionally included or not.)

Comment: @ScottDudley hi Sott, I am getting this error:  The plugin is in an invalid state, DIS
ABLED, that doesn't support a transition to enabled.  Most likely, it was disabled due to a timeout.

Comment: Were there any errors prior to that? What happens if you mouse over that line and click "Enable", then check the status (and logs) again? Sounds like the plugin might have gotten disabled on a previous upload for some reason, which left it in a disabled state, and upload a new version would not automatically enable it.

Comment: tells me module cannot be modified lol

Comment: Is there anything in the logs when you try disabling and re-enabling the entire add-on? Also, I can't tell if the "disabled" module in the screenshot actually refers to your <gadget> because the names don't match up. Can you please edit your post to include the entire atlassian-plugin.xml?

Comment: @ScottDudley I added the entire plugins and removed the leading slashes from the gadget.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55146/discussion-between-eduardo-dennis-and-scott-dudley).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have one plugin descriptor nested inside another plugin descriptor. (I'm surprised that it actually passed validation!)

Change this:

```
<atlassian-plugin name="Hello World" key="example.plugin.helloworld" plugins-version="2">
  <plugin-info>
    <description>A basic gadget module</description>
    <vendor name="Atlassian Software Systems" url="http://www.atlassian.com"/>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </plugin-info>

  <gadget key="unique-gadget-key" location="gadget.xml"/>

</atlassian-plugin>
```

to just this:

```
  <gadget key="unique-gadget-key" location="gadget.xml"/>
```